# Как сделать ротацию баннеров?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать ротацию баннеров с помощью javascript, чтобы когда заходишь на страницу сайта, отображается один баннер, а после перезагрузки страницы отображается другой баннер и т.д.?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы говорите о смене баннера при перезагрузке, то Javascript не нужен - измените только серверную часть. В зависимости от количества баннеров, будет выгодно либо (а) выбирать все баннеры из базы, генерировать случайное число от 0 до (количество баннеров - 1) и писать в HTML баннер по получившемуся индексу, либо (б) узнать через COUNT(*) количество баннеров в базе -> опять же число -> выбрать нужный из БД -> на страницу.

Answer (score 1):

Если всё-таки хотите использовать JavaScript с перезагрузкой страницы, то сохраняйте в куки последний индекс баннера, который показывается сейчас. Тем самым при перезагрузке страницы показывайте любой баннер из тех, что есть, кроме того, что в куках и ставите новую куку :)

Answer (score 0):

Если всё-таки хотите использовать JavaScript и без перезагрузки страницы, то используйте таймер. На [этом](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) сайте есть хороший пример с обновлением стрелок часов.

Answer (score 0):

```
var b = new Array();
b.push('bannerCode1');
b.push('bannerCode2');
b.push('bannerCode3');
document.getElementById('bannerContainer').innerHTML = b[Math.floor(Math.random()*b.length)];
```

`bannerCode1`, `bannerCode2`, `bannerCode3` - html-коды баннеров, `bannerContainer` - id блока баннеров.